# Can I run SSRS reports against TFS Online?

Tags: .net-framework, team-foundation-server

We're using TFS online (http://tfs.visualstudio.com/) and would like to do some reporting against test cases and test plans (as it looks like there's no way to export this information to Word in any logical format).

I found the following solution http://communitytfsreports.codeplex.com/releases/view/92081 which is perfect but which unfortunately comprises of RDL (SSRS Report) files.

Is there a way I can deploy and use these against TFS Online? I'm quite new to the technology and have come up short trying to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with TFS online:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ac56447d-2a58-4620-b3cf-d73025552f97/are-there-any-reports-for-the-agile-template-in-tfs-online